# is it possible to limit Listener widget to only response for two direction

Tags: flutter, dart, swipe

i am trying to only detect swipe left and swipe right using `Listener Widget`

i implement the following code , and it is work perfect but the problem is that is work for all direction UP DPWN LEFT RIGHT , i handle this using delta <0 and > 0 though , but can't understand why this response for all directions ..

does it possible to limit it for only swipe right && left ?

Note: GetureDetecteor does not suit with my code , tha's why i use `Listener`

```
Listener(
      onPointerMove: (moveEvent){
        if(moveEvent.delta.dx > 00) {
          print('swipe left');
         
        }
        if  (moveEvent.delta.dx < 0){
           print('swipe right');
       
        }
```

}
)

Comment: add `if (moveEvent.delta.dy.abs() > moveEvent.delta.dx.abs()) return;` (or something similar) before your `if`s

Comment: yes sensitive became better but not 100% .. it is accept up down too sometimes

Comment: when finger go fast up-down it is not accept up or down , but if finger scrolling slow up-down it is accept up down

Comment: if (moveEvent.delta.dy.abs() > moveEvent.delta.dx.abs()) return; result is : accept up down if finger go slow up or down .....  if (2*moveEvent.delta.dy.abs() > moveEvent.delta.dx.abs()) return; i tried tll 6* ,, same result .. i put aadditional check  if ( moveEvent.delta.dx.abs() > 64) return; .. same result